# How can I optimize Astar for vast empty spaces?

Tags: c++, godot, a-star

I am creating a game with a 3D grid for flying entities, So I have a lot of points and connections in the air where there aren't any obstructions. I didn't want to decrease the resolution of my grid so I thought I could just skip over chunks (or empties as I call them) of the Astar map while they're not containing any obstructions, and I modified Godot's Astar algorithm to do this.

Unfortunately this ended up being slower than looping through points one at a time due to the way I implemented this modification, which needs to loop through all the edge points of an empty.

2D representation of how one edge point of an empty connects to all other edge points: [image: 2D representation of how one edge point connects to all other edge points]

This ends up looping through a larger number of points than letting the A* algorithm work it's way through the empty.

So I'm sorta stumped on how to make this more efficient while still preserving the most optimal path.
I could potentially narrow down what faces of the empty should be scanned over by first comparing the center points of all 8 faces of the empty (as my grid consists of hexagonal prisms). Or maybe I should somehow use the face center points of the empty's faces exclusively instead of all edge points.

I mainly want to know if anyone has worked on an issue like this before, and if so what would be the recommended solution?

Here is the astar loop for reference:

```cpp
bool AStar::_solve(Point *begin_point, Point *end_point, int relevant_layers) {
    pass++;

    //make sure parallel layers are supported
    // or if *relevant_layers is 0 then use all points
    bool supported = relevant_layers == 0 || (relevant_layers & end_point->parallel_support_layers) > 0;
    if (!end_point->enabled || !supported) {
        return false;
    }

    bool found_route = false;

    Vector<Point *> open_list;
    SortArray<Point *, SortPoints> sorter;

    begin_point->g_score = 0;
    begin_point->f_score = _estimate_cost(begin_point->id, end_point->id);
    open_list.push_back(begin_point);

    while (!open_list.empty()) {
        Point *p = open_list[0]; // The currently processed point

        if (p == end_point) {
            found_route = true;
            break;
        }

        sorter.pop_heap(0, open_list.size(), open_list.ptrw()); // Remove the current point from the open list
        open_list.remove(open_list.size() - 1);
        p->closed_pass = pass; // Mark the point as closed

        //if the point is part of an empty, look through all of the edge points of said empty (as to skip over any points within the empty).
        OAHashMap<int, Point*> connections;

        PoolVector<Empty*> enabled_empties;
        

        int size = p->empties.size();
        PoolVector<Empty*>::Read r = p->empties.read();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

            
            Empty* e = r[i];
            

            supported = relevant_layers == 0 || (relevant_layers & e->parallel_support_layers) > 0;
            //if the empty is enabled and the end point is not within the empty
            if (e->enabled && supported && !end_point->empties.has(e)) {
                enabled_empties.append(e);
                //can travel to any edge point
                for (OAHashMap<int, Point*>::Iterator it = e->edge_points.iter(); it.valid; it = e->edge_points.next_iter(it)) {
                    int id = *it.key;
                    Point* ep = *(it.value);
                    ep->is_neighbour = false;
                    //don't connect to the same point 
                    if (id != p->id && (i == 0 || !connections.has(id))) {
                        connections.set(id, ep);
                    }

                }
            }

        }

        
        
        //add neighbours to connections
        for (OAHashMap<int, Point*>::Iterator it = p->neighbours.iter(); it.valid; it = p->neighbours.next_iter(it)) {
            int id = *it.key;
            Point* np = *(it.value);// The neighbour point
            np->is_neighbour = true;
            //don't need to check for duplicate point connections if no empties
            if (size == 0 || !connections.has(id)) {

                //don't add points within enabled empties since they're meant to be skipped over
                if (np->empties.size() > 0 && !np->on_empty_edge) {
                    bool in_enabled_empty = false;
                    PoolVector<Empty*>::Read r1 = np->empties.read();
                    for (int i = 0; i < np->empties.size(); i++) {
                        if (enabled_empties.has(r1[i])) {
                            in_enabled_empty = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!in_enabled_empty) {
                        connections.set(id, np);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    connections.set(id, np);
                }
                

            }
        }
        
        


        for (OAHashMap<int, Point *>::Iterator it = connections.iter(); it.valid; it = connections.next_iter(it)) {
            Point *e = *(it.value); // The neighbour point

            //make sure parallel layers are supported
            // or if *relevant_layers is 0 then use all points
            supported = relevant_layers == 0 || (relevant_layers & e->parallel_support_layers) > 0;
            

            if (!e->enabled || e->closed_pass == pass || !supported) {
                continue;
            }

            real_t tentative_g_score = p->g_score + _compute_cost(p->id, e->id) * e->weight_scale;

            bool new_point = false;

            if (e->open_pass != pass) { // The point wasn't inside the open list.
                e->open_pass = pass;
                open_list.push_back(e);
                new_point = true;
            } else if (tentative_g_score >= e->g_score) { // The new path is worse than the previous.
                continue;
            }

            e->prev_point = p;
            e->prev_point_connected = e->is_neighbour;

            e->g_score = tentative_g_score;
            e->f_score = e->g_score + _estimate_cost(e->id, end_point->id);

            if (new_point) { // The position of the new points is already known.
                sorter.push_heap(0, open_list.size() - 1, 0, e, open_list.ptrw());
            } else {
                sorter.push_heap(0, open_list.find(e), 0, e, open_list.ptrw());
            }
        }
    }

    return found_route;
}
```

Note: I'm still not exactly sure what the `sorter` does.

the entire code can be seen here in [a_star.cpp](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.5/core/math/a_star.cpp) and [a_star.h](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.5/core/math/a_star.h)

---

### Edit:

if anyone wants to reference or use [this](https://github.com/KnightNine/godot/blob/3.5-Astar-experimental/core/math/a_star.cpp), I've modified the Astar code to add user-defined octants and to use a user-defined straight line function (they are user-defined so they can work with any type of grid) to be used between octants when possible to further decrease runtime, and it works very well in terms of speed. Though the pathing is not optimal, especially when adding a lot of obstacles/restricting the available positions.

Comment: Just a random though... would it work to convert the 3D grid into an octree and run A* over the octants? That could reduce your problem space quite a bit.

Comment: Before changing your entire algorithm, it can be useful to run it with code instrumentation / profiling to identify the hot-spots. The results may surprise you.

Comment: @Wolph if you mean to use the center points of the octants/empty spaces as the Astar points, I don't think that would preserve the optimal pathing. Since these center points would become a sort of track that the pathfinder would have to "get on" which may make the path not optimal. But maybe there's a way to circumvent this issue. I'm thinking about how I could make it work.

Comment: @Wolph or do you mean to split up the grid into an oct tree, run the pathfinding over the octants, then pathfind whilst restricting the grid used to the coords within those octants?

Comment: @DED I was thinking of the latter. Using the octree to do pathfinding over the octants so you can get a rough path to restrict your grid to. That could make the exact pathfinding much faster.

Comment: @Wolph so I'm doing that now, the issue I'm seeing is that my grid is layered for different pathfinding restrictions,  So the octree would need to be different for each layer due to these differences in what can be navigated over, unless I want to just have 1 generic octree and just have it be less efficient.

2nd issue is that the octants would need to be dynamically split from changes to the grid, and I'll need to figure out how to do that efficiently.

I'll start with just having the static octree and see if i'll need those optimizations later.

Comment: An alternative option could be to approximate the answer. Instead of solving the pathfinding exact, just go for a very rough estimate and gradually increase precision if needed. Or you could even go for a genetic algorithm and/or monte carlo method approach. Oftentimes "good enough" works just fine :)